# Sharing SAMBA shares across subnets

Tags: samba

I have **Samba** servers dotted around different regions all connected via site to site IPSEC VPN,

I can `ssh` into each one using their respective IP’S. I have main region, and sub regions. This issue is basically about sharing samba across subnets.

I created a test share, public, open to the network.  I can access this from the main region to the sub region, and then I can create the same sort of share on the main region and no problem.

Viola! A samba share across subnet that works, bar no user password protection.

Then I add a group and some users into the group and I force the share to become accessible only by that group. And that’s when it goes crazy.

Works from the sub regions to the main region without a problem however, trying to browse to the sub region from the main region wont work.  It asks me for the `username` and `password` but just keeps asking and asking. (actually knowing what log records this might be helpful too, I can't seem to find it)

Usernames and passwords work locally on all the samba regions.

To make things weirder. I have a 2003 server, that runs DNS and WINS, of which I had disabled wins for the most part while testing. It was also the VPN server, well still is. And this is weird, *but* if I connect to the 2003 VPN server. I can connect to any samba share I want, (provided I supply the right `username` and `password`)

So in a nutshell.

- Site to Site IPSEC
- Samba shares work locally both sub and main region
- Samba share with users and groups work locally both sub and main region
- sub regions can access main region with users and groups and plain shares
- Main region can access sub regions plain shares
- Main region can't access sub region password shares, however, can do so when connected to windows VPN server.

If I try to connect to the share without the VPN, it just keeps asking over and over for my `username` and `password`.

Please help.

Comment: anywahy, you need to post your samba configurations and logs

Comment: ...was this ever resolved?